# Can different properties be defined for the same edge labels but different connecting vertex labels?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am curious if something like this is allowed and works as expected:

```
schema.edgeLabel("CreatedBy")
    .properties("createdDate")
    .connection("Entity","User")
    .create()

schema.edgeLabel("CreatedBy")
    .connection("Attribute","User")
    .create()
```

I wonder if I run both against the schema if the would only allow property `createdDate` between `Entity` and `User` but not between `Attribute` and `User`. Right now it says that `CreatedBy` already exists, so I have it like that (which isn't constraining the way I want)

```
schema.edgeLabel("CreatedBy")
    .properties("createdDate")
    .connection("Attribute","User")
    .connection("Entity","User")
    .create()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create 2 different edges if you'd like different properties to be used on the application of the edge.

To understand your requirements though, you'd like the ability to use the same edge name to define different relationships and then associate different edge properties aligned to each relationship, yes?

Comment: yes that's correct.. I guess I could use a superset of the needed properties and just have the others are optional.. is that viable?